# SAS LAG function issue (Not in conditional clause)

Tags: sas

The code with LAG and if function doesn't work the way I expected. I know how to correct it. However, I am looking for help to understand why it is happening. I know lag will have issues with conditional statement, however my lag function is out of if statement.

I am having issues with the 2nd ID record.  For the id#2, record #2, the prior should be 0 instead of 2.  I don't understand why.

```
    data a;
input  vid 1. rid 2. flag 3. ;
datalines;
1 1 0
1 2 1
1 3 1
1 4 0
2 1 0
2 2 0
2 3 0
2 4 2
;
run;

/*incorrect version*/
data b;
set a;
by vid;
 Cumflag+flag;
   /*Keep track of prior record running total*/
   put (vid rid flag CumFlag)(=) ;
   Priorflag=lag(Cumflag);
   put (vid rid flag CumFlag PriorFlag)(=) ;
    if first.vid then do;
   Cumflag=flag;
   Priorflag=0;
     put (vid rid CumFlag PriorFlag)(=) ;
end;
run;

/*correct version*/
data c;
set a;
by vid;
 Cumflag+flag;
   /*Keep track of prior record running total*/
    if first.vid then   Cumflag=flag;

      Priorflag=lag(Cumflag);
      if first.vid then    Priorflag=0;
run;
```

Output dataset B is as follows. 
Having issue with vid=2  prio=2.

[vid   rid flag    Cumflag Priorflag 

1   1   0   0   0 

1   2   1   1   0 

1   3   1   2   1 

1   4   0   2   2 

2   1   0   0   0 

2   2   0   0   2 

2   3   0   0   0 

2   4   2   2   0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WAdYP.png)

```
Log file is here. 

vid=1 rid=1 flag=0 Cumflag=0
vid=1 rid=1 flag=0 Cumflag=0 Priorflag=.
vid=1 rid=1 Cumflag=0 Priorflag=0
vid=1 rid=2 flag=1 Cumflag=1
vid=1 rid=2 flag=1 Cumflag=1 Priorflag=0
vid=1 rid=3 flag=1 Cumflag=2
vid=1 rid=3 flag=1 Cumflag=2 Priorflag=1
vid=1 rid=4 flag=0 Cumflag=2
vid=1 rid=4 flag=0 Cumflag=2 Priorflag=2
vid=2 rid=1 flag=0 Cumflag=2
vid=2 rid=1 flag=0 Cumflag=2 Priorflag=2
vid=2 rid=1 Cumflag=0 Priorflag=0
vid=2 rid=2 flag=0 Cumflag=0
vid=2 rid=2 flag=0 Cumflag=0 Priorflag=2 (*** having question here, since cumflag=0 prior**)
vid=2 rid=3 flag=0 Cumflag=0
vid=2 rid=3 flag=0 Cumflag=0 Priorflag=0
vid=2 rid=4 flag=2 Cumflag=2
vid=2 rid=4 flag=2 Cumflag=2 Priorflag=0
```

Comment: The choice of using variable name `PriorFlag` misconstrues it's role of really being `PriorCumFlag`, especially when there is already a `Flag` variable.

Comment: Richard, thank you for your comment. Agree.

Answer (score 0):

The LAG() function does not retrieve the value from the previous observation. It just retrieves the value from the list of previous values you have passed in. The value that is lagged is the value that variable has when the LAG() function runs. That is why you normally do not want to execute the LAG() function conditionally.

The first program is lagging the value of CUMFLAG **before** resetting CUMFLAG on the first observation in the BY group. The second program is lagging the value of CUMFLAG **after** it has been reset.

Comment: Tom, Can you please explain further.

Comment: Tom, Can you please explain further.  For the first code, for id #2, record 1, the first record's cumulative flag is initially set to be 2( carried over), and the prior flag is also 2 (lag function), then since it is the first record for id#2, both cumulative flag and prior flag will be reset to 0.  Then SAS will go to id #2, record 2 to define cumulative and prior.  By then, the prior should be already lag of previous cumulative with value 0.  So why id #2 record #2 has a prior value of 2 in the output then?

Comment: Since the first call to LAG() for ID 2 pushes in the value of CUMFLAG, which is 2, then the next time that LAG() statement runs it returns that value.  You are getting confused because the value of CUMFLAG is changed **after** it was captured by the LAG() function.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Tom.  Suggest adding a PUT statement so you can see the values.

```
data b;
set a;
by vid;
 Cumflag+flag;
   /*Keep track of prior record running total*/
   Priorflag=lag(Cumflag);
   put (vid flag CumFlag PriorFlag)(=) ;
    if first.vid then do;
   Cumflag=flag;
   Priorflag=0;
end;
run;
```

returns

```
vid=1 flag=0 Cumflag=0 Priorflag=.
vid=1 flag=1 Cumflag=1 Priorflag=0
vid=1 flag=1 Cumflag=2 Priorflag=1
vid=1 flag=0 Cumflag=2 Priorflag=2
vid=2 flag=0 Cumflag=2 Priorflag=2  ***
vid=2 flag=0 Cumflag=0 Priorflag=2  ***
vid=2 flag=0 Cumflag=0 Priorflag=0
vid=2 flag=2 Cumflag=2 Priorflag=0
vid=3 flag=0 Cumflag=2 Priorflag=2
vid=3 flag=0 Cumflag=0 Priorflag=2
vid=3 flag=1 Cumflag=1 Priorflag=0
vid=3 flag=3 Cumflag=4 Priorflag=1
```

Note that for the first record with vid=2, the value of CumFlag at the time lag() is executed is 2.  This means the value 2 is put into the lag queue.  Then for the second record with vid=2, the value of CumFlag is 0 when the lag executes, so this value is entered into the lag queue and it returns 2.

BTW, there lag function works correctly conditionally. The key to understanding lag is remembering that it is a queue.

Comment: thank you Quentin. I love you suggestions to add "PUT" statement to see the values.

Comment: However, I still not 100% get it.  I revised the code.

Comment: Quentin, Can you take some time to look the revised the code and output? I am trying to understand the output line by line for id #2.

Comment: For the first ID #2 record, before you call the LAG(CumFlag) function the values are `vid=2 rid=1 flag=0 Cumflag=2` Thus the value of 2 is written to the queue.  For the second ID #2 record when you call LAG(CumFLag) it returns 2 from the queue, because it is the previously entered value.

Answer (score 0):

The `LAG<n>()` function is a FIFO stack/queue of size `<n>`.  `LAG` is simply a stack with one item.

LAG(variable) does the following, at the point of invocation:

- retrieve return value from bottom of stack
- shift all stack values down 1
- push variable value to top of stack

The unconditional use of `LAG` in a data step with will return the variable value from the prior implicit iteration; typical use with `SET` causes the value returned to be that from the prior row.